# requests + grequests: is the "Connection pool is full, discarding connection:" warning relevant?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, grequests

I'm hosting a server on localhost and I want to fire hundreds of GET requests asynchronously. For this I am using `grequests`. Everything *appears* to work fine but I repeatedly get the warning:

> WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Connection pool is full, discarding connection: date.jsontest.com

A search shows how the full pool issue can be avoided when creating a `Session()` in `requests` e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632794/in-requests-library-how-can-i-avoid-httpconnectionpool-is-full-discarding-con). However, a couple of things:

1. Even if I don't take any steps to avoid the warning, I appear to consistently get the expected results. If I do use the workaround, any requests over the number of the `pool_maxsize` will give a warning.
2. The linked workaround will still result in the warning if the number of requests exceeds the pool size. I assumed there would be some kind of throttling to prevent the pool size being exceeded at any one time
3. I can't seem to find a way to disable the warning. `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` doesn't seem to do anything.

So my questions are:

1. What does this warning actually mean? My interpretation is that it is simply dropping the requests from firing, but it doesn't seem to be the case.
2. Is this warning actually relevant for the `grequests` library, especially when I take steps to limit the pool size? Am I inviting unexpected behaviour and fluking my expected result in my tests?
3. Is there a way to disable it?

Some code to test:

```
import grequests
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() # Doesn't seem to work?

session = requests.Session()

# Hashing the below will cause 105 warnings instead of 5
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100, 
                                            pool_maxsize=100)
session.mount('http://', adapter)

# Test query
query_list = ['http://date.jsontest.com/' for x in xrange(105)]

rs = [grequests.get(item, session=session) for item in query_list]
responses = grequests.map(rs)
print len([item.json() for item in responses])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) What does this warning actually mean? My interpretation is that it
>   is simply dropping the requests from firing, but it doesn't seem to be
>   the case.

This is actually still unclear to me. Even firing one request was enough to get the warning but would still give me the expected response.

> 2) Is this warning actually relevant for the grequests library,
>   especially when I take steps to limit the pool size? Am I inviting
>   unexpected behaviour and fluking my expected result in my tests?

For the last part: **yes**. The server I was communicating with could handle 10 queries concurrently. With the following code I could send 400 or so requests in a single list comprehension and everything worked out fine (i.e. my server never got swamped so it must have been throttling in some way). After some tipping point in the number of requests, the code would stop firing any requests and simply give a list of `None`. It's not as though it even tried to get through the list, it didn't even fire the first query, it just blocks up.

```
sess = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=10, 
                                            pool_maxsize=10)
sess.mount('http://', adapter)  

# Launching ~500 or more requests will suddenly cause this to fail
rs = [grequests.get(item[0], session=session) for item in queries]
responses = grequests.map(rs)
```

> 3) Is there a way to disable it?

Yes, if you want to be a doofus like me and hash it out in the source code. I couldn't find any other way to silence it, and it came back to bite me.

**SOLUTION**

The solution was a painless transition to using [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) instead. The following code behaves exactly as expected, gives no warnings and, thus far, scales to any number of queries that I throw at it.

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession(max_workers = 10)
fire_requests = [session.get(url) for url in queries]
responses = [item.result() for item in fire_requests]
```